# SqlException - Value too long for column (Corda)

Tags: corda

getting above exception during flow execution (state persistence). My contract state includes a field with type ByteArray, assigned value is an XML file 14kb long. I suspected an exception such as this might occur with a large data field member...so have I ran into a design constraint of Corda or should I be using another type (e.g. Blob/Clob?), if so is the solution simply to define the member of type Blob/Clob in the schema or is there another approach I should take? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Corda uses an H2 database. Try using a Clob data type instead (it's explicitly recommended for XML: http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#clob_type).

In the future, Corda will not be tied to H2, and different rules will apply depending on the database used.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that documentation...but it looks like I need access to the connection object in order to create a clob/blob. Hence my question, as it feels that in order to do this would considerable modification at the H2/Kyro level with possible ramifications up to Corda serialisation. Would this be an accurate observation? Am I correct then in concluding there is no "out of the box" support for persisting data longer than 255 bytes as *transaction state* in Corda???

Comment: You do not need a connection object, just define your types in your custom contract state class.

You can define any valid data type and length for a given database provider within your contract state (for example in H2 you can use BLOB with a maximum size of 2Gb). See http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html. 
Internally data type mapping to database providers is handled by Hibernate, not Corda.

Comment: Yes, that's what I actually did..I was referring to the instantiating a BLOB object for assignment into the custom contract state at runtime. Anyway, I've decided to use attachments so didn't pursue that much further tbh; reference the associated SecureHash of the attachment from the contract data state. Seems to work well, and I assume a better approach as the data being referred to isn't intrinsically a unique aspect of the state. Unless there's a potential issue I'm not seeing?